# SwiftUI: How to get window in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swiftui, uiscenedelegate

```
let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
if let sd: SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate) {
    let window = sd.window
}
```

this is in Swift, I want to convert this into Objective-C. I have tried this:

```
UIScene *scene = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]connectedScenes]allObjects]firstObject];
```

but now there is no `SceneDelegate`; in Objective-C there is UIKit's [`UIWindowSceneDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate?language=objc).

also I wasn't able to access UIScenedelegate. Scenedelegate is in Swift and I am trying to get window in objective-c
but now I'm not able to access window in swiftUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `scene.delegate` to make sure it conforms to the protocol, then cast the protocol on it so the compiler will let you use the protocol properties and/or methods.

```
UIScene *scene = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes] allObjects] firstObject];

if([scene.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIWindowSceneDelegate)]){
    UIWindow *window = [(id <UIWindowSceneDelegate>)scene.delegate window];
}
```